# Fix Error: unable to resolve module './index.android' from ' '

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Running into this error trying to build react-native v0.61.5 app with react-navigation on android. iOS runs fine, not sure why im getting this index.android file error because I thought react-native merged index files  into just the singlular `index.js` as the entry point.

this is the full error:

> Loading dependency graph, done. Error: Unable to resolve module
>   `./index.android` from ``:
>
> None of these files exist:   *
>   index.android(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
>   * index.android/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/name/Desktop/Development/app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/name/Desktop/Development/app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/name/Desktop/Development/app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
>       at /Users/name/Desktop/Development/app/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42
>       at Server. (/Users/name/Desktop/Development/app/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1088:41)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/name/Desktop/Development/app/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
>       at _next (/Users/name/Desktop/Development/app/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)

here's index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "appName",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "algoliasearch": "^4.0.3",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-instantsearch-native": "^6.3.0",
        "react-native": "0.61.5",
        "react-native-agora": "^2.9.1-alpha.2",
        "react-native-algolia-dropdown": "^1.6.0",
        "react-native-calendars": "^1.220.0",
        "react-native-chart-kit": "^4.3.0",
        "react-native-code-push": "^6.0.0",
        "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
        "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
        "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.26.1",
        "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
        "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^9.13.6",
        "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
        "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.11.2",
        "tipsi-stripe": "^7.5.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.7.5",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.7.6",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
        "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
        "eslint": "6.7.2",
        "jest": "24.9.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

project structure
[image]

Libraries are integrated properly, any advice?

Comment: Upgrade react-native-cli?

Comment: @Jim you either install `@react-native-community/cli` to your app modules by `yarn add @react-native-community/cli` or use `npx` to start and run the app, `npx react-native start` and `npx react-native run-android`.

Comment: react-native-cli has zero effect over this stop with that suggestion. because changing does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's throwing error because it's not able to find index.android file in your root directory of project , if you have index.ios in your project

> You can you create index.android.js file and in that import original
>   index.js file and check if it works (quick fix)

So Basically After React v0.49, you don't need index.ios.js and index.android.js. You only need the index.js:

> But There are two cases when this issue arise

- **If you are updating from an old project you need to make sure the correct files are loaded from native code to adopt the new single file entry point**.
- **And second is inconsistent behaviour of react native as some people randomly getting this issue** in newer version because of watchman or cache

Solution for first case

```
//For android in this directory you need to make this change android/app/src/main/java/<yourPackage>/MainApplication.java

private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
  //...
  @Override
  protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
  }
};
```

//and for ios in this directory ios//AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  //...
}
```

These two solution also works in some cases

- watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-*

or

- remove index.ios.js and index.android.js files and create a single
  index.js

There are certain scenarios so it's hard to determine why anyone is getting this issue.

Comment: there is no index.android and no index.ios files. and there never have been, and I wasn't having this problem before

Comment: @Jim can you create index.android.js file and in that import original index.js file and check if it works

Comment: that works, although I was mostly curious why it was happening randomly in the first place, but anyway If you'd like to restructure your answer, and provide as much detailed understanding as to any possible reasons react-native randomly enforces looking for the `index.android` file out of nowhere, maybe in combination with `react-navigation`, ill award your bounty

Comment: @Jim Great good to hear that ,I've updated the answer and i've put my detailed understanding for this issue I hope this will solve your query.

Comment: absolutely wonderfully informational answer. well deserved bounty

Comment: I was using a ReactNativeHost (with react native 0.62.20) in my existing android application and that one has `index.android` by default in getJSMainModuleName -> overwriting that fixed it

Comment: Interestingly enough, I only needed the android fix. For some reason only the Android project was looking for index.android, yet my iOS one correctly only looked for index

Answer (score 1):

Run the packager with cache-clean:
`npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: just tried. cleaned, rebuilt, and re-installed beforehand also. the behavior persists

Answer (score -1):

It's solved for me with

```
react-native link
```

Comment: `link` is not necessary in >0.60